# Freeing memory after allocation error (realloc)

Tags: c, malloc, free, realloc

The first if statement below checks if, while adding elements to an array, we've reached the end of the buffer size. If we have, it duplicates the original size.

```
while (token != NULL) {
    tokens[position] = token;
    position++;

    if (position >= bufsize) {
      bufsize += LSH_TOK_BUFSIZE;
      tokens_backup = tokens;
      tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
      if (!tokens) {
        free(tokens_backup);
        fprintf(stderr, "lsh: allocation error\n");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }
    }

    token = strtok(NULL, LSH_TOK_DELIM);
}
```

The very last if statement checks for an allocation error, and if that happened, it frees `tokens_backup`, which points to the original `tokens`.

Why is tokens_backup needed here?

If there was in fact an allocation error couldn't they simply free the original `tokens`?

The declaration of both are:

```
char **tokens = malloc(bufsize * sizeof(char*));
char *token, **tokens_backup;
```

Comment: Generally speaking it is nonsense to free one particular memory allocation just before exiting with an error code. I understand you are slightly confused about this code, and in my opinion that code shouldn't be there.

Comment: @Cheatah One may choose to keep the allocations/free's in perfect sync to not have to create suppression rules for `valgrind` and LeakSanitizer (if LeakSanitizer even supports suppression rules). It's often easier to keep it clean than to filter out "_leaks that are ok_".

Comment: In those cases it would make more sense to call a full cleanup & exit routine, rather than be concerned with only the most recent `realloc` and exiting uncleanly. But I guess that's largely opinion-based. But I see your point.

Answer (score 3):

*"If there was in fact an allocation error couldn't they simply free the original tokens?"*

No we can't, because we've lost the original `tokens`

If the allocation in `tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char*))` fails, `tokens` will be `NULL` and the pointer we want to free is lost, so the memory can't be freed anymore. Therefore we need to store the original `tokens` pointer in `tokens_backup` so we can free `tokens_backup`.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. if tokens_backup is pointing to tokens and the allocation failed, wouldn't we also lose tokens_backup?

Comment: @hendrix no, `tokens_backup` won't magically change unless you assign something else to it. If `realloc` fails, it returns `NULL`, that's all. `tokens_backup` will still point to the same place where `tokens` pointed before `realloc`

Comment: The `realloc` function promises "If realloc() fails the original block is left untouched; it is not freed or moved." So the memory area is still safe to use, but in order to do so you would need to have a reference to it. Otherwise you would simply have a memory leak. @TedLyngmo made a good point of that in the comments to the question. But in this case I wouldn't worry about it because the programming is exiting anyway. This would only be satisfying the memory debugger.

Answer (score 2):

Some quotes from the C Standard relative to the function `realloc` (7.22.3.5 The realloc function)

> 3. ...If memory for the new object cannot be allocated, the old object is not
>    deallocated and its value is unchanged

and

> 4 The realloc function returns a pointer to the new object (which may
> have the same value as a pointer to the old object), **or a null
> pointer if the new object could not be allocated.**

In your code snippet the pointer `tokens` points to the allocated memory. In this statement

```
tokens = realloc(tokens, bufsize * sizeof(char*));
```

if the memory can not be reallocated then the function `realloc` returns a null pointer that is assigned to the pointer `tokens` overwriting the previous values stored in the pointer. That is in this case the pointer tokens will be a null pointer and the address of the previously allocated memory will be lost. So you will be unable to free the previously allocated memory. As a result there will be a memory leak because as it is written in the first provided quote the previously allocated memory will not be freed by the function `realloc` itself.

Having a duplicated pointer before calling the function realloc you can free the previously allocated memory using this duplicated pointer in such a case.